# how to access columns if they are named after numbers

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, quoted-identifier, postico

My column names in my table are just numbers from 0-20, where each column is corresponding to a number however,
when I try

```
    select 0 from table
```

I get output of only zeroes in my column, how can I select a column without changing the column names?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html#r_names-delimited-identifiers

Answer (score 3):

```
select "0" from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try select [0] from table. Your way is replicating zeros for all entries in the table

Comment: SQL uses double quotes to escape invalid identifiers. Square brackets are use to reference array elements